Run a command whose absolute path is stored in a variable
I have a script below, which stores the absolute path of FZF in a variable named fzf_cmd. I want to execute FZF using this variable. It works in Bash but not in Zsh.
f1.sh
fun() {
    local fzf_cmd
    [[ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]] && fzf_cmd="$(type -P fzf)"
    [[ -n "${ZSH_VERSION}" ]] && fzf_cmd="$(type -p fzf)"
    "${fzf_cmd}" --height 40%
}

fun

I get the following error message in ZSH.
fun:4: no such file or directory: fzf is /home/rishi/commandline-plugins/fzf/bin/fzf

However, when I run fzf explicitly using its absolute path (/home/rishi/commandline-plugins/fzf/bin/fzf), it works as expected in Zsh.
Am I missing anything here? How can I get it to work in both of the shells?
EDIT:
The command type -p fzf in Zsh doesn't only print the absolute path of fzf. It prints fzf is /home/rishi/commandline-plugins/fzf/bin/fzf. That was the cause of the issue. I think using whence would be better here!

Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85250

What is the output of type -p fzf? It could be that the output is fzf is /home/rishi/commandline-plugins/fzf/bin/fzf and to execute line 4 you only need /home/rishi/commandline-plugins/fzf/bin/fzf.

I see the command type -p fzf in zsh doesn't only return absolute path of fzf. It returns in the format fzf is /home/rishi/commandline-plugins/fzf/bin/fzf. I think that's why it's not running.

@user202311 Yes, I just found it! Naive, mistake! :)

Why are you using type at all? If fzf is on the user's search path, then fzf --height 40% will work fine. If not, type isn't going to return anything useable as as a command name (even ignoring the wordiness of type's output).

usually with bash I would recommend bash "${fzf_cmd}" --height 40%. Does the same not work for z? zsh "${fzf_cmd}" --height 40%

@Kashyap fzf isn't  a shell script, so neither of those would work.

As an aside, command -v fzf will print just that path to the executable fzf, whether you are using bash or zsh, just as the POSIX spec requires.

@chepner I have observed that command -v or command -V doesn't work always. For example, in case if fzf is an alias.

Using the empty string returned by type -P fzf in that case as a command name won't work, either. If your goal is to run the "raw" command fzf and not an alias or function wrapping it, just use command fzf.

@RishiK. if it's an executable (and not a shell script) then for bash just use -c. I.e. bash -c '"${fzf_cmd}" --height 40%'

You got the zsh variant wrong. This should work:
fun() {
  local fzf_cmd
  if [[ -n "${BASH_VERSION}" ]]; then
    fzf_cmd="$(type -P fzf)"
  elif [[ -n "${ZSH_VERSION}" ]]; then
    fzf_cmd==fzf
  fi
  "${fzf_cmd}" --height 40%
}

type -p fzf provides too much noise in zsh. While you could use ksh-style whence -p fzf, using the builtin =cmd filename expansion mechanism makes it shorter and more efficient as it avoids forking a process to get the output of a command through a pipe.
UPDATE
Detailed explanation, as requested by the OP:
In the original approach, the use of type -p fzf would have worked, if this command would output only the absolute path of fzf and nothing else, which it unfortunately does not.
Therefore I used the trick with filename expansion: For a word w, the term =w expands to the first absolute path of w, found in the variable path (respectively $PATH).
BTW, we could also write it without testing the shell version, using the command which:
fun() {
  "$(/usr/bin/which fzf)" --height 40%
}

This ensures that always an external program named fzf is invoked, bypassing  a possible function (or alias) of the same name. The disadvantage compared to the approach using =-expansion is, that with which we always create a child process to calculate the path to fzf, while =fzf runs inside the parent shell; no forking needed.
UPDATE
It just occurred to me that an even simpler solution would be to use the command command, which works in bash and in zsh:
fun() {
  /usr/bin/command fzf --height 40%
}

This would also bypass a function or alias named fzf and ensure that only an executable (external command) named fzf gets invoked.
UPDATE
Using absolute path to which and command for compatibility with bash and zsh.

NIce, I like this solution. But do you mind explaining how this works? or maybe guide me to its explaination in the official Zsh documentation.
From the documentation, this seems to be parameter expansion. Ref:https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion
However, as per the documentation, it does word splitting but doesn't seem to explain this behavior as per my understanding!

@RishiK : Done. Now really everything is explained in detail.

Great! Thanks a lot!

"$(which fzf)" doesn't work with zsh's which builtin if fzf is an alias or function. See also Why not use "which"? What to use then? for reasons it may not work with other implementations either.

Beware while zsh's command (which predates POSIX') only runs external commands, POSIX/bash's command bypasses function lookup but not builtins (unlikely for fzf to ever become a builtin of any shell though). See also the command -e of yash for external commands only there.

@StephaneChazelas : You are right with which, so I replaced it with =which, to ensure that alias/function lookup is bypassed. command in zsh always skips aliases and functions, and I think it also bypasses builtins: command : x returns command not found: :, since : is a builtin command.

The goal of the OP is to invoke a binary fzf and bypass any alias, function or builtin of the same name; for, if he would not want to bypass it, he would simply have written fzf and not fiddled around with type -p or type -P

@StephaneChazelas : Now I got your point. I updated my which to /usr/bin/which and the command to /usr/bin/command, to ensure identical behaviour under zsh and bash. Well, once you try to write code which works the same in two languages, you open a door to the hell....

Not all systems have a /usr/bin/which or /usr/bin/command. The latter is not found on Ubuntu 22.04 for instance (and /usr/bin/which there can be one of several implementations through the dpkg-alternatives framework).

@StephaneChazelas : I had hoped that the Linux distributions are at least the same in this respect. If this is not the case: The OP did not specify, which distro he is using, and at least he can adapt my solution to his requirements....
